# Putting variable constraints on the right of an equation

Tags: math-mode

Suppose I have a formula like y/x, and I want to say that x must be greater than zero.

In well-printed literature, you'd see something like

y/x ;   x > 0

with just the correct amount of spacing between the formula, the semicolon, and the constraint.

I'm keen not to hardcode those spacings and am *sure* LaTeX can do it for me. But how?

(Currently, I use $$\frac{y}{x} \hspace{0.5in}; x \geq 0$$)

Comment: What do you mean by correct amount of spacing?

Comment: Statistically speaking, the most typographically pleasing. LaTeX is much better than me at doing this.

Comment: Is this OK? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
      &y/x; && x>0
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}`

Comment: Not much better than what I currently do: \frac{y}{x} \hspace{0.5in}; x \geq 0

Comment: LaTeX can't guess everything: the most typographically pleasing spacing for LaTeX is perhaps not so pleasing, or not so pleasing to you. Anyway, typical typographical spacings are `\quad` and `\qquad`, respectively ‘quadrat’ which lengths depend on the font in use, and ‘double quadrat’. You may use one of them instead of `\hspace{0.5in}`.

Comment: in the example you show, the space around the semicolon looks like the space for a relation.  even if it isn't, this input would produce that spacing:  $ y/x \mathrel{;} x > 0 $

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, don't hesitate to use natural-language words rather than terse symbolism to express a side condition, a thought, etc. For instance:

[image]

(Since `x` is in the denominator, `x>0` seems more appropriate than `x\geq 0`...)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\dots\ $y/x$, with $x > 0$.
\end{document}
```